# Java MM/dd/yy simple date DateTimeFormatter not working for greater than 2037

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Actually, I found problem with `MM/dd/yy` date format : 
If enter year greater than `37` then the year format reflects as `1937`.

i.e, if I enter input as `02/05/37` then  when I am printing this date into console the date changes into `02/05/1937`.

if he  entered less than `02/05/37` then working fine.

```
Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").parse("01/01/47");
System.out.println(startDate);
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The format 02/0/37 is not unambiguous. I guess it is a question of definition which century you use.

Comment: Are you using `DateTimeFormatter` as the title states, or `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: I am using DateTimeFormatter joda time

Comment: In that case: be sure to show us some code

Comment: Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").parse("01/01/47");
    System.out.println(startDate);                                                    same problem with SimpleDateFormat .it will print  Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1947

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using `SimpleDateFormat`: It's conform specifications that 02/05/37 is parsed as 02/05/1937. At least for the next year or so...

Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has to decide in which century your date should be. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created. 2037 is within 80 years before the current date (2016), so it uses a time in the past.

Comment: There is any solution for it if  "01/01/47" then i will get Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2047

Comment: @BhushanUniyal `if(date.getTime() < 0) {date.setYear(date.getYear()+100));}`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct. You need to understand `SimpleDateFormat` behavior for assuming your intended century.

You are using old outmoded classes. The new recommended classes have a different behavior on this issue.

## java.time

The java.time framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the old java.util.Date & SimpleDateFormat classes.

The behavior about assuming century is different. In the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class, a two-digit century is interpreted as being in the 21st century, resulting in a year **within the range 2000 to 2099** inclusive.

The java.time classes include `LocalDate` for representing a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "02/01/47";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

> 2047-01-02

By the way, a tip: **Avoid two-digit years** if at all possible. The confusion and trouble induced is not worth the savings of two bytes and a smudge of toner.

Comment: I beg to differ on the last point, if just a slight bit. If a million people are going to use your GUI hundreds of times a day, and you know the date will always be within the next 50 years, you will have $$ savings on users entering two digits rather than four, as long as you know how to process the input in accordance with the requirements.

Comment: @OleV.V. Granted, you should do what's best for your customer and users. Myself, I've worked with many bookkeepers and accountants and none of them preferred 2-digit years. A four-digit is instantly recognizable more as a word than a number, making for easier reading. Perhaps for some folks the best option might be the combination: 2-digit year for data-entry and 4-digit for display.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't supply century info, then it has to make an assumption and it quite reasonably assumes that you are going to want mostly dates in the past, with some scope for future dates, but not too far, as it's more likely that you'll want prior dates, such as birth dates, etc. And people quite commonly live up to about 80 years of age. So far more dates will be in the past for any given current date, than future ones, based on this assumption.

From the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)...

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"),
>   SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some
>   century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before
>   and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.
>   For example, using a pattern of "MM/dd/yy" and a SimpleDateFormat
>   instance created on Jan 1, 1997, the string "01/11/12" would be
>   interpreted as Jan 11, 2012 while the string "05/04/64" would be
>   interpreted as May 4, 1964. During parsing, only strings consisting of
>   exactly two digits, as defined by Character.isDigit(char), will be
>   parsed into the default century. Any other numeric string, such as a
>   one digit string, a three or more digit string, or a two digit string
>   that isn't all digits (for example, "-1"), is interpreted literally.
>   So "01/02/3" or "01/02/003" are parsed, using the same pattern, as Jan
>   2, 3 AD. Likewise, "01/02/-3" is parsed as Jan 2, 4 BC.
>
> Otherwise, calendar system specific forms are applied. For both
>   formatting and parsing, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more,
>   a calendar specific long form is used. Otherwise, a calendar specific
>   short or abbreviated form is used.

So, if you to do something with this, then you'll need to check if the formatted date is prior to today's date (or some other cut off that you choose) and just add 100 years to the given date, if you wish to only have future dates or beyond a different cut off from the default one.